# How to create a different password reset link in the email message for the api route and the web route on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-passport, laravel-api

so I'm trying to make a forgot password function for the route API
and web route when the user accesses the function he will get an email containing a link to reset the password. and the link in the email will be different depending on the route the user uses.

example:
When a user accesses the API route, the link that the user will receive is http://website.com/api/password/reset, and when the user accesses the web route he will receive the link http://webiste.com/password/reset

I've tried using `Request :: is ('api *')` and it runs smoothly on the local server, but when I deploy to heroku the `Request :: is ('api *')` command doesn't work so the link sent points to the web route I used `Request :: is ('api *')` inside `ResetPasswordNotification`

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    /**
     * The password reset token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $token;

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to create the reset password URL.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $createUrlCallback;

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Create a notification instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

        if (static::$createUrlCallback) {
            $url = call_user_func(static::$createUrlCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        } else {
            $request = new Request;
            if($request->is('api*')){
                $url = url(route('api.password.reset', [
                    'token' => $this->token,
                    'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset(),
                ], false));
            }else{
                $url = url(route('password.reset', [
                    'token' => $this->token,
                    'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset(),
                ], false));
            }
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when creating the reset password button URL.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function createUrlUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$createUrlCallback = $callback;
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

the command above ran smoothly without any errors on the local server, but didn't work on heroku.

I beg your help to solve this problem.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use helper method `request()` to get current request from anywhere in your Laravel application.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request